# in c# ,one array of class and two connected instance of it why?

Tags: c#, class

I wrote the code below :

```
1. MyClass[] origArr=new MyClass[3];  
2. MyClass[] arr1;
3. // filled the array with objects and did some work on it .  
4. dgv_1.DataSource=origArr;  
5. 
6. // Here is the problem :
7. arr1=origArr;  
8. // do some work on arr1 ...  
9. dgv_2.DataSource=arr1;
```

For some reason the data in 'origArr' changed when data in 'arr1' change ...
I thought that maybe this happened because 'origArr' and 'arr1' are pointers referring to the same object so I changed line '7' to :

```
7. origArr.CopyTo(arr1,0);
```

but it didn't work ... what can i do to make the pointers referring to different objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line 7 copies the **reference** to `origArr` into `arr1`, so they point to the same physical array.

Even a `Clone` or `CopyTo` won't help much: you will get a copy of the array structure, but in there the references to your oringinal classes are copied. So you end up with a new array with still the same objects.

You will need to Clone your MyClass objects and put those clones into a new array.

Comment: Many thanx for u .. as i understood i declared 'arr1' as @Andrey said and made a for loop and created a new MyClass() object with the same values in 'origArr' : arr1=new MyClass() { MyProp=orig[i].Myprop };
and it worked ... i hope that this the right way to do it .

Comment: Yes that will work: by copying all properties, you make an independent clone of the original MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

In c# variable holds reference, not the value. to copy it do

```
MyClass[] origArr=new MyClass[3];  
MyClass[] arr1 = new MyClass[3];
origArr.CopyTo(arr1,0);
```

you have to allocate memory by yourself

Comment: what do you mean it didn't work? please be specific. i tried, it works.

Comment: this is the code i tried it :


                Class1[] a = new Class1[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = new Class1();
                a[i].MyProperty = i;
            }
            Class1[] b = new Class1[3];
            a.CopyTo(b, 0);
            b[1].MyProperty = 6;


but it gives the same result as my code...changes happened in both arrays.

Comment: so follow first answer about cloning

Answer (score 1):

You need to change line 7 to  `origArr.CopyTo(arr1,0);` as you noted.  But you also need to initialize the arr1 array.

```
1. MyClass[] origArr=new MyClass[3];   
2. MyClass[] arr1=new MyClass[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use

`Array.Copy(src , dest, lenght)`